# Bootstrap multiple-item carousel: Only show 1 on small screens

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, mdbootstrap

I'm using this carousel:
https://mdbootstrap.com/snippets/jquery/ascensus/135508#html-tab-view

If you resize the window to phone size, you see there is only **ONE card** displaying.

Now when you look at the next it's not actually the next card but **the next first card** from the **second slide**.

This is because all but the first card in a slide have

```
<div class="col-md-4 clearfix d-none d-md-block">
```

instead of

```
 <div class="col-md-4">
```

the `clearfix d-none d-md-block` will hide the element for all screen sizes except on medium. When I don't use it, it shows all 3 even on small screens.

**Is there any way to show every card after another and not just the first from each slide?**

Comment: The snippet link seems to be broken.

Comment: @SiddharthBhansali sorry, added the working link!

Comment: MDBootstrap seems to have a breakpoint feature for carousels, if you're using the pro version: https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/plugins/multi-item-carousel/#section-breakpoint , however I don't see any way in which you can do it without using some sort of JS. Or, one way could be having 2 carousels, 1 for the small screens, and another for large screens.

Comment: How could i do it with JS? Don't really want one carousel for small screens and one for bigger screens, than there are many duplicates

Comment: Theoretically speaking, you'd need to detect screen size changes. So when it changes to small, you'd need each card to be a separate `carousel-item`. And then undo the change when the size goes back to large.

Comment: ouf, I think that's not possible, how am I supposed to open new slides for every card and then redo this

Comment: Impossible, no. But sure is a lot of unnecessary work, and I don't recommend either. The best thing to do here is to go with the 3 cards on top of each other. I'd update here if I can think of something else!